# CLion - how to configure to attach to existing process for debugging a .dylib

Tags: debugging, clion, lldb, dylib, dsym

I am developing a plugin for a third-party host application on MacOS that compiles as a .dylib (with associated DSYM directory). The .dylib and DSYM directory is automatically copied to the host's plugin directory by a supplied build script. The build script uses `clang` to build the .dylib. The host application is able to open the plugin.

With Xcode, I am able to debug the .dylib with `lldb` within Xcode, because Xcode is somehow able to identify that the sources match the dylib once it is loaded.

I wish to set up a similar system with CLion, however I have not been able to get CLion to associate the breakpoint lines in the source with the dylib. When I create a breakpoint in the source it warns me that "Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line". I almost expect this kind of warning because the image hasn't been loaded into the host application yet. However loading the plugin does not trigger the breakpoints.

I tried setting the Configuration's Executable to the .dylib, and setting the working directory to the location of the .dylib and the DSYM directory (this is what I have to do when running lldb manually), and this does not seem to help.

My questions are:

1. Does CLion use `lldb` internally?
2. Is what I am trying to do possible with CLion?
3. If so, what is the correct configuration for this situation?

One important thing to note is that I am not building the .dylib with CLion directly, it is build by an external build system, I am just trying to debug the resulting image with CLion, which I understand should work (it works with Xcode & lldb at least). I have a basic `CMakeLists.txt` that is sufficient for CLion to understand the code base, but it is not used to build it (beyond any background compilation that CLion might do to check syntax etc).